# Generate X.509 Certificate from Base64 string in Nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, base64, x509

Suppose I have a Base64 certificate string and.

I know how to generate a x509 certificate in `C#` code,

```
string base64CertificateString = "MIIxxxxxxxx....xxxx";
string password = "xxxxxxxx";
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64CertificateString);
X509Certificate2 x509certificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
```

How can I do the same thing in `Nodejs`?

Comment: Did you ever find anything for this?